# Selection with SwiftUI Table

Tags: swiftui

I have some data, that is displayed in a `Table`. The user can go forward and backwards to see the different data. I want, that the selection is getting saved. In the background it is working, the main problem now is, that the selection will not get updated on the table. I simplified the code to show the problem:

```
struct TableRow: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let col1: String
    let col2: String
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var selection: Int? = nil
    
    @State private var savedSelection1: Int? = nil
    @State private var savedSelection2: Int? = nil
    
    let infos1 = [
        TableRow(id: 1, col1: "Infos 1 - Row 1 - Col 1", col2: "Infos 1 - Row 1 - Col 2"),
        TableRow(id: 2, col1: "Infos 1 - Row 2 - Col 1", col2: "Infos 1 - Row 2 - Col 2"),
        TableRow(id: 3, col1: "Infos 1 - Row 3 - Col 1", col2: "Infos 1 - Row 3 - Col 2")
    ]
    let infos2 = [
        TableRow(id: 4, col1: "Infos 2 - Row 1 - Col 1", col2: "Infos 2 - Row 1 - Col 2"),
        TableRow(id: 5, col1: "Infos 2 - Row 2 - Col 1", col2: "Infos 2 - Row 2 - Col 2"),
        TableRow(id: 6, col1: "Infos 2 - Row 3 - Col 1", col2: "Infos 2 - Row 3 - Col 2")
    ]
    @State var infos = [TableRow]()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Table(self.infos, selection: self.$selection) {
                TableColumn("Col 1", value: \.col1)
                TableColumn("Col 2", value: \.col2)
            }
            
            HStack {
                Button("Infos 1") {
                    self.savedSelection2 = self.selection
                    self.infos = infos1
                    self.selection = self.savedSelection1
                }
                Button("Infos 2") {
                    self.savedSelection1 = self.selection
                    self.infos = infos2
                    self.selection = self.savedSelection2
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

The problem is: SwiftUI changes the content and immediately after the selection. This change of selection is too fast. So I tried to make a test and this code proved it:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var selection: Int? = nil
    
    @State private var savedSelection1: Int? = nil
    @State private var savedSelection2: Int? = nil
    
    let infos1 = [
        TableRow(id: 1, col1: "Infos 1 - Row 1 - Col 1", col2: "Infos 1 - Row 1 - Col 2"),
        TableRow(id: 2, col1: "Infos 1 - Row 2 - Col 1", col2: "Infos 1 - Row 2 - Col 2"),
        TableRow(id: 3, col1: "Infos 1 - Row 3 - Col 1", col2: "Infos 1 - Row 3 - Col 2")
    ]
    let infos2 = [
        TableRow(id: 4, col1: "Infos 2 - Row 1 - Col 1", col2: "Infos 2 - Row 1 - Col 2"),
        TableRow(id: 5, col1: "Infos 2 - Row 2 - Col 1", col2: "Infos 2 - Row 2 - Col 2"),
        TableRow(id: 6, col1: "Infos 2 - Row 3 - Col 1", col2: "Infos 2 - Row 3 - Col 2")
    ]
    @State var infos = [TableRow]()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Table(self.infos, selection: self.$selection) {
                TableColumn("Col 1", value: \.col1)
                TableColumn("Col 2", value: \.col2)
            }
            
            HStack {
                Button("Infos 1") {
                    self.savedSelection2 = self.selection
                    self.infos = infos1
                    Task {
                        try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 100_000)
                        self.selection = self.savedSelection1
                    }
                }
                Button("Infos 2") {
                    self.savedSelection1 = self.selection
                    self.infos = infos2
                    Task {
                        try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 100_000)
                        self.selection = self.savedSelection2
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

The only change is, that I have a `Task.sleep` before change the selection. this works.

My question is now: This is a pretty ugly solution. The sleep must not be too short, because otherwise it will not work. If it is too long, I will see this delay.

Any ideas how I can solve this problem better?

**EDIT**

I am using this code on macOS. As told in one answer, the problem doesn't occur in iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could only reproduce the issue when running the code on macOS – on iOS (in Simulator) for me it worked fine as is.

I solved the issue on macOS by wrapping the selection setting in `DispatchQueue.main.async`:

```
            HStack {
                Button("Infos 1") {
                    self.savedSelection2 = self.selection
                    self.infos = infos1
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { // here
                        self.selection = self.savedSelection1
                    }
                }
                Button("Infos 2") {
                    self.savedSelection1 = self.selection
                    self.infos = infos2
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { // here
                        self.selection = self.savedSelection2
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I didn't test on iOS, thanks for that hint (I will update the question). Your solution is working, but: why? ;)

Comment: Maybe it works in the simulator because it is slow enough

Answer (score 0):

To avoid being dependent on some timing issue this could be solved by introducing a new state property and using `task(id:)` to handle selections

First create a new property that holds the latest button being pressed

```
@State private var buttonPressed = .none
```

I created a simple enum for keeping track of the buttons

```
enum ButtonState {
    case button1, button2, none
}
```

Then we update it in the `Button` action for each button

```
HStack {
   Button("Infos 1") {
       self.infos = infos1
       buttonPressed = .button1
   }
   Button("Infos 2") {
       self.infos = infos2
       buttonPressed = .button2
   }
}
```

And then we act on changes of `buttonPressed` by using `.task(id:)` with our new property as the id value

```
.task(id: buttonPressed) {
   switch buttonPressed {
   case .button1:
       savedSelection2 = selection
       selection = savedSelection1
   case .button2:
       savedSelection1 = selection
       selection = savedSelection2
   case .none:
       selection = nil // or break
   }
}
```

This is enough for the UI to be updated properly without needing any time of sleep functionality.

Comment: `TableRow` is a built in type so I would recommend you change the name to something else.